# Magento: modify free shipping method label with various shopping cart price rules

Tags: php, magento

I need to setup free shipping in my Magento catalog for three Shopping Cart Price Rules, and I need the label of "free shipping" to be different in each scenario. I know how to modify the label for all instances of free shipping globally via Configuration/Shipping Methods/Free Shipping by editing Title and Method Name fields, but I want to control Title and Method Name depending upon which Shopping Cart Price Rule applies.

Example:
Shopping Cart Rule 1 returns "Title 1, Method Name 1, $0.00"
Shopping Cart Rule 2 returns "Title 2, Method Name 2, $0.00"
Shopping Cart Rule 3 returns "Title 3, Method Name 3, $0.00"

Answer (score 0):

use following custom script

```
$quote=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
 $data=$quote->getShippingAddress()->getAllShippingRates();
  foreach($data as $_rate){
   if($_rate->getCode()=='freeshipping_freeshipping'){

     $_rate->setCarrierTitle('new carrier name'); /* new carrier title here */
     $_rate->setMethodTitle('new method title');/* new method title here */
     $_rate->save();

    }
  }
```

Comment: Where would I put this script? in shipping.phtml somewhere?

Comment: put in here app/code/Mage/Checkout/controller/OnepageController.php

Comment: on SavePaymentAction method, after " $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');"

Comment: and on "saveShippingMethodAction" method, before  "$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals();"

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working. I am assuming that 'freeshipping_freeshipping' is the id that has to be used in the shopping cart price rule, under Rule Name or Labels?

Comment: Would I just add else if statements to the script for the other two carriers, changing the ID 'freeshipping_freeshipping' to something unique for each carrier?